# Display an inverted right angled number pyramid

Tags: python

The main question asks to display an inverted right angled number pyramid by using "while loops" but the use of nested loops is prohibited and the numbers should be from 1 to 5

[image]

The image above is the pyramid that needs to be printed by using loops but use of nested loops is prohibited
There is a hint provided too which needs to be used

Hint - Here, you gotta loop in the range 1 to 6. With this, you'll also need an extra variable, like count = 5.
So in loop 1, print('1 '*count) will give 1 1 1 1 1. And remember to decrease the count by 1 inside the loop!

Comment: Try to figure out an algorithm using pen and paper first

Comment: *"Questions asking for homework help [...] must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."* -- from the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Here's a hint: in Python, you're able to print a string repeatedly using the * operator, so figure out how many times you need to print the number out in each iteration and use that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, the first line has 1 and it repeats 5 times, next line, it has 2 and it repeats 4 times, 3rd line has 3 and it repeats 3 times and so on. So the pattern is, at i^th line, it has i, (6-i) times. So design a loop which will print in such way. Your code:

```
i=1
while i<=5:
   print((6-i)*str(i))
   i+=1
```

Comment: It didnt help bruv

Comment: It didnt help completely in the hint it is mentioned to make a variable before the loop

Comment: i know it makes the code inefficient but its the rule and no i still didnt get the answer

Comment: I know the difference between while loop and for loop and adding a variabke was mentioned in the hint

Comment: But please edit the answer by using the hint and give me the code